# Which Klingon ship is most representative during the TNG era?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, spaceship, klingon

I want to buy a few Eaglemoss starships fitting the TNG era, such as Enterpise D, Romulan Warbird (the kind that is like a biplane with scoops), Ferengi Marauder, and a Cardassian Galos class ship. There seems to be many different kinds of Klingon ships, and I can't readily tell which fits this time period. Is there a particular one that appeared most often within the TNG series, therefore being best representative as a typical Klingon ship?

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Klingon_Bird-of-Prey probably

Answer (score 8):

Well if you can only have one the Vor'cha class is the battle cruiser of the TNG era.
https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vor%27cha_class

I'd opt against the bird of prey as those were introduced in star trek III and are not uniquely TNG era.

Vor'cha was the first new klingon class on screen meant to be in the lineage of the classic era D7 and movie era K'tinga.

The much much larger Negh'var did appear in the future setting of TNGs finale and introduced in use in Deep Space Nine but these weren't fleet ships this was more like the klingon Air Force One.
https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/IKS_Negh%27Var

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't be surprised if the Bird of Prey had more appearances in TNG, but the Vor'cha was the one introduced in TNG, so I think it feels more representative. (Like there were loads of Reliant and Excelsior class ships in TNG, but you wouldn't pick them over a Galaxy or Nebula class ship to represent the Federation circa TNG.)

Answer (score 3):

The **Bird or Prey** is the most common Klingon ship. It appeared in [12 TNG episodes and 29 DS9 episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_starships).

Here are a few notable TNG episode examples:

S2: *Matter Of Honor*: Riker served aboard the Pagh

S3: *Yesterday's Enterprise*: Battle scenes

S4: *Reunion*: Gowron and Duras's ships

S4/5: *Redemption 1 and 2*:  Battle Scenes, Worf served aboard Kern's ship, the Bortas

S5: *Unification*: Picard and Data travelled to Romulus

S7: *First Born" and "Generations Movie*: The Duras sisters' ship

Comment: And while that's true, it's repeatedly called out as being archaic.